# Share balance between lnd and bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon

I have a bitcoind instance with some balance. When I run lnd (which is connected to this bitcoind instance) it seems to use its own wallet. Is there any way I can use lnd with the bitcoind balance without having to send the coins to lnd wallet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible. `lnd` and `bitcoind` are two separate daemons, that interact with the bitcoin network in different ways.

The only way I could think of doing this would be to import keys from one daemon to the other, but exploring the `help` command of `lnd` I'm not currently seeing any options to import or export private keys.

In any case, I think sharing keys across the daemons may in fact be dangerous, as `bitcoind` will not recognize funds as being locked in a LN channel. So if `bitcoind` tried to spend a LN channel UTXO, it may cause a total loss of that channel's funds (since your published transaction was not the LN channel's most recent state, the counterparty would broadcast the revocation transaction, and all funds would be spent to them). Perhaps someone with a deeper knowledge of these daemons could comment, but by my reasoning I believe this would be true